# Volume of all Voronoi cells in n-dimensional bounded space

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, surfaces, triangulations, convex-hulls

How can one find the volume of **all** Voronoi cells (bounded and unbounded) in an $n$-dimensional bounded space? For instance, consider an $N$-dimensional space (hypercube) with bounds on each dimension from $[0,1]$. Consider $K$ points for which Voronoi tessellation is constructed. One can use the approach stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634993/volume-of-voronoi-cell-python/54265278#54265278?newreg=d981f3c2c0514d3a9f29b9daf29b7c30) to compute hypervolume of all bounded Voronoi cells. How can one find the hypervolume of all open / unbounded Voronoi cells considering that they are bounded within the $N$-dimensional hypercube?

Alternatively, is there a way to *roughly estimate* the hypervolume of unbounded Voronoi cells, say by sampling many points in such cells, or by other means?